# How to get the selected value using material-dropdown?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Following their example I am trying to get the selected value to dispatch it after that to my action but can't find any way to get it. Any help?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown';

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      category: undefined,
    }
  }
  onPost = () => {
    var { category } = this.state;
    console.log(category) // Undefined
  }
  render() {
    let category = [{
      value: 'Banana',
    }, {
      value: 'Mango',
    }, {
      value: 'Pear',
    }];

    return (
      <Dropdown
        label='Favorite Fruit'
        data={category}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPost}>
         <FontAwesome name="check" size={25} color="white" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onChangeText` method to get the currently selected value. You can also send it via props to a handler method and use it as your app needs.

Example:

```
render() {
  (...)
  <Dropdown
    label='Favorite Fruit'
    data={category}
    onChangeText(value => this.onChangeHandler(value)}
  />
  (...)
}

const onChangeHandler = (value) => {
  console.log(`Selected value: ${value}`);
}
```

Hope it helps